# My code's output corrupts after importing "widget" library in Corona

Tags: lua, widget, coronasdk

My code was working properly but after including widget library, the output got messy. Can you please tell me what is the problem?

```
--Include sqlite
local sqlite3 = require "sqlite3"
local widget = require "widget"

W=display.contentWidth
H=display.contentHeight

--Open library database file
local path = system.pathForFile("library", system.ResourceDirectory)
db = sqlite3.open( path )   

title = display.newText("LIBRARY", 0, 0, nil, 30)
title.x = W/2 title.y=50

--Access records of book table and display them as nx2 grid with title and cover.
xOffset = 10
yOffset = 100  
items = display.newGroup()
for row in db:nrows("SELECT * FROM book") do
   local text = row.bookName
   local img = display.newImageRect("img"..row.bookId..".jpg", 200, 200 )
   local t = display.newText(text, 0, 0, nil, 25)
   t.x = img.x
   t.y = img.contentBounds.yMax+50
   item = display.newGroup(img,t)
   item.anchorChildren = true
   items:insert(item)
   items.anchorChildren = true

   if(xOffset==10) then
     item.anchorX, item.anchorY = 0,0
     item.x = xOffset
     xOffset = W-10
     item.y = yOffset
     --t:setTextColor(0,255,0)
   else
     item.anchorX, item.anchorY = 1,0
     item.x = xOffset
     xOffset= 10
     item.y = yOffset
     yOffset = yOffset+item.contentBounds.yMax-50
     --t:setTextColor(255,0,0)
   end 
end
```

EDIT:

Before including widget:

[image]

After including widget:

[image]

Comment: What is the problem? What is going wrong? What are you expecting to happen instead? Simply adding that `local widget = require "widget"` causes whatever it is that is going wrong to go wrong? Removing that fixes the problem (whatever that problem is)?

Comment: I want to add scrollView to my objects so I need widget. However, it is giving the messy output in my edited question when I only include the widget.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, clearly the objects in the `items` display group are what have been affected - see how the library text isn't in that group and it stays where it is.

Just after the x and y of the item is set, print out its position. Also print the position and dimensions of the group - this will give you a better understanding of where the positioning is being taken from, or where the origin (0,0) is at.

```
local i = 1;
for row in db:nrows("SELECT * FROM book") do
    local text = row.bookName
    local img = display.newImageRect("img"..row.bookId..".jpg", 200, 200 )
    local t = display.newText(text, 0, 0, nil, 25)
    t.x = img.x
    t.y = img.contentBounds.yMax+50
    item = display.newGroup(img,t)
    item.anchorChildren = true
    items:insert(item)
    items.anchorChildren = true

    if(xOffset==10) then
        item.anchorX, item.anchorY = 0,0
        item.x = xOffset
        xOffset = W-10
        item.y = yOffset
        --t:setTextColor(0,255,0)
    else
        item.anchorX, item.anchorY = 1,0
        item.x = xOffset
        xOffset= 10
        item.y = yOffset
        yOffset = yOffset+item.contentBounds.yMax-50
        --t:setTextColor(255,0,0)
    end 
    print("--------")
    print("Item "..tostring(i).." is at ("..tostring(item.x)..","..tostring(item.y)..")")
    print("Item group now at ("..tostring(items.x)..","..tostring(items.y)..")")
    print("Item group size = width:"..tostring(items.contentWidth)..", height:"..tostring(items.contentHeight))
end
print("--------")
```

Compare the output for with/without including widget and you should be able to find the problem.

Comment: Thanks, James. My problem was compatibility issue. I updated my Corona SDK and then without using anchor points and other stuff, I set my display group objects by taking the center as reference points.

Comment: Glad it's all sorted!